# my python program don't connect to my data base

Tags: python, sql, localhost

pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1")

when I execute my program I get this problem if anyone can help please ,

```
def insert():
     nomcomplet=entryName.get()
     adresse=entryadr.get()
    
     saison=entrySEM.get()
    
     
     nombre_de_chambre=entryCHEM.get()

     if nomcomplet == "" or adresse == "" or saison == "" or nombre_de_chambre == "" :
         messagebox.showinfo("insert status","all field are requireds")
     else :
         con= pymysql.connect(host='localhost',port=3307,user="root" ,password="", db="miniprojet",local_infile=True)
         cursor = con.cursor()
         cursor.execute("insert into `moha` (nomcomplet,adresse,saison,nombre_de_chambre)")
         cursor.execute("commit");

         MessageBox.showinfo("insert status", "inserted successfully")
         con.close();
```

that's the fonction of connection

Comment: Are you sure the query: "insert into `moha` (nomcomplet,adresse,saison,nombre_de_chambre)" is correct ?

Comment: i don't know really I'm not expert in python . is there anything I should change